# How to see NVTX markers in Nvidia Nsight Systems? With host and guest being the same Windows machine

Tags: graphics, profiling, nvidia, nsight, nvtx

I am trying profiling CPU/GPU applications, using Nsight suite.

Currently trying to understand a stuttering problem, I added a range around the simulation step (taking place on the CPU):

```
#include "3rd/nvToolsExt.h"

int main()
{
    // ...
    nvtxRangePush("Simulation");
    scene.update(gSimulationDelta);
    nvtxRangePop();
    // ...
    return 0;
}
```

After configuring the VS solution and copying the DLL next to the `.exe`, the application compiles, links and run as expected.

Using the Visual Studio extension `NVIDIA Nsight Integration 2020.2.0.0`, I launch a `Nsight Systems 2022.3.4` Trace.

In the prepopulated project, I check **Collect NVTX trace**.

I click **Start** and get a report. Yet the NVTXmarkers are absent from the **Timeline View**, and I have several NVTX related warnings in **Diagnostics Summary**.

Notably:

- > NVTX_INJECTION64_PATH variable is missing from the environment variables of the process. Make sure the process was appropriately launched.
- > No NVTX events collected. Does the process use NVTX?

As a last resort idea, I added the system-wide environment variable `NVTX_INJECTION64_PATH` with the value `C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\Nsight Systems 2022.3.4\target-windows-x64\ToolsInjection64.dll`, but after relaunching everything the issue stays the same, and all warnings are still present.

How to have Nsight Systems show NVTX markers ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I work on Nsight Systems and NVTX.  A few things:

I don't see anything wrong with what you're doing, so it's likely a bug in the tools.  Can you try launching your program directly from the standalone Nsight Systems GUI program instead of using the Visual Studio integration?  That will determine if the problem is with Nsight Systems itself or the Visual Studio integration.  Be sure to check the box in the Nsight Systems project to "Collect NVTX Trace", as you mentioned doing in VS.

You should not set `NVTX_INJECTION64_PATH` yourself.  Nsight Systems will set this environment variable automatically for any processes it launches with NVTX capture enabled.  The only time you'd ever want to set this variable manually is if you write your own tool that captures NVTX calls.

And one last thing:  This shouldn't affect the problem you are having here, but it looks like you are using an older version of NVTX that required linking against the nvToolsExt DLL.  While the old version works fine and is still supported, I recommend switching to version 3, which is a header-only implementation of the same API, so linking against the DLL is no longer required.  The new version's headers are located in the `nvtx3` subdirectory, so to ensure you're using v3, the best practice is to include the directory name in your #include:

`#include <nvtx3/nvToolsExt.h>`

...and adjust your project's include search paths appropriately.  The NVTX v3 headers ship with Nsight Systems and the CUDA Toolkit, so you probably already have them.  You can also download them from github:

https://github.com/NVIDIA/NVTX/tree/release-v3/c/include

The old NVTX version that requires a DLL will be deprecated in CUDA 12, so it's a good idea to migrate any projects using NVTX to v3 soon.

Comment: thank you for your answer and the different points you raised. In particular, moving forward to the `nvtx3` header found in `C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\Nsight Systems 2022.3.4\target-windows-x64\nvtx\include` solved my issue, as I now see the NVTX ranges appearing in Nsight System. I will mark your answer as accepted (maybe you can highlight the section about upgrading to nvtx3 as a good first thing to try ; ). I can also confirm it worked when launching from `NVIDIA Nsight Integration`.

Comment: Two remarks though: The warning regarding `NVTX_INJECTION64_PATH` missing from the environment variables of the process is still present. The one stating that No NVTX event was collected is **not** present anymore, but there is one saying "Not all NVTX events might have been collected." I do not know if these can be addressed?

Comment: Thanks for the replies!  I will edit my response to reorder things now that we know what happened.  I will also file a bug to investigate not getting events when using the old NVTX version, because that needs to still be supported.  And I think the warning message about NVTX_INJECTION64_PATH should be handled better -- we want to catch the case where someone removes that variable programmatically, but clearly that isn't happening here.  Similar for the "Not all events..." messages -- those seem to happen more than necessary, so hopefully can improve when we show those.

Comment: I had to manually set NVTX_INJECTION64_PATH  on Windows, otherwise it was not set by Nsight Systems and no NVTX trace was generated. After setting it, all worked well.

NVTX_INJECTION64_PATH=C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\Nsight Systems 2022.2.1\target-windows-x64\ToolsInjection64.dll